# How to get a Grid column width in pixels in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, width, pixel

Column widths are specified in different ways (Stars, Auto etc)
How to get the width in pixels of a specific column?

```
GridLength l=tip.basis.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` property of elements to get the width/height of elements.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607827/what-is-the-difference-between-width-and-actualwidth-in-wpf) describes the difference between `'ActualWidth' and 'Width'.

So in the above example it would be:

```
Double width = tip.basis.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth;
```

And also keep in mind that WPF uses Device Independent Pixels, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153227/device-independent-pixel).

Answer (score 3):

The `ActualWidth` property should provide the width of the column in Pixels

[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.actualwidth.aspx) property to get the width. It represents

> The width of the column in device-independent units (1/96th inch per
>   unit).